# API REST Yammer: cant retrieve admins from a group

Tags: api, yammer

using the REST API i did that with the JavaScript SDK :

```
yam.platform.request({
    url: "users/in_group/2490226",
    method: "GET",
});
```

I retrieved users but I can't see which one is an admin

Can I retrive the admins of a group using the REST API?

Comment: the documentation did not explained what i was searching for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the group/{group id}/members.json call, the list of returned users will include the "is_group_admin" field.

Here is an example:
https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/groups/**4767132**/members.json

4767132 is your groupID. The json response will include a list of users where a single user record looks like this:

```
    {
        "type": "user",
        "id": 1526232831,
        "name": "yam5dummy",
        "state": "active",
        "full_name": "yam5dummy",
        "job_title": null,
        "network_id": XXXXXX,
        "mugshot_url": "https://mug0.assets-yammer.com/mugshot/images/48x48/no_photo.png",
        "mugshot_url_template": "https://mug0.assets-yammer.com/mugshot/images/{width}x{height}/no_photo.png",
        "url": "https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/users/1526232831",
        "web_url": "https://www.yammer.com/XXXXX.com/users/1526232831",
        "activated_at": "2014/10/01 16:12:03 +0000",
        "auto_activated": false,
        "stats": {
            "following": 1,
            "followers": 1,
            "updates": 0
        },
        "email": "yam5.dummy@XXXXX.com",
        "is_group_admin": true,
        "group_member": {
            "state": "approved"
        }
    },
```

**Notice the    "is_group_admin": true,**

Comment: Thx, I didn't see this one.

Comment: Note that this API is undocumented. Therefore, it's subject to change at any time and is not formally supported. Use at your own risk.